# Like FourWaySplitter but different

Tags: python, wxpython

Using Python 2.6, wx.Python:

Wonder if someone might know how to build a four panel window w/o using FourWaySplitter.  (Unless I am wrong FourWaySplitter will do what I am about to describe.  With FourWaySplitter any change of the size of any sub-panel changes the size of ALL sub-panels.)

Here is what I need:

ONE vertical split and two **INDEPENDENT** horizontal splits one on each of the newly split vertical parts. (sounds simple but after a day of trying every permentation of splitters and sizers, I have finally admitted defeat.)

Anyway the idea is that only the vertical splitter would change the size of all four windows.  The horizontal splitter on the left side of the vertical one would change only the two windows/panels on the left of the vertical splitter, and the horizontal splitter splitter on the right of the vertical splitter would change only the two windows/panels on the right of the vertical splitter.

A concrete working example would be a lot of help and greatly appreciated and if you come to my house I will make you some pancakes.

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty confusing for me too. Fortunately, I wanted to write an article on the subject and I finally figured it out after a couple of hours a month or three ago. I still haven't written the article, but I paired down my example a little for this answer. Hopefully you can follow it:

```
import random
import wx

########################################################################
class RandomPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        color = random.choice(["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"])
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)               

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # create the sizers
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        twoSplitSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        verticalSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)

        # create the left side
        leftSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(verticalSplitter)
        panelOne = RandomPanel(leftSplitter)
        panelTwo = RandomPanel(leftSplitter)
        leftSplitter.SplitHorizontally(panelOne, panelTwo)
        leftSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        # create the remote side
        rightSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(verticalSplitter)
        panelThree = RandomPanel(rightSplitter)
        panelFour = RandomPanel(rightSplitter)
        rightSplitter.SplitHorizontally(panelThree, panelFour)
        rightSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        verticalSplitter.SplitVertically(leftSplitter, rightSplitter)
        verticalSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        sizer.Add(verticalSplitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="4-Way Split", size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I use the random colors just to make it easier to distinguish between panels. Normally, you'd have different widgets on each panel. Anyway, this works for me on Windows with wxPython 2.8.11

Comment: Thank you Mike.  This is a much more natural "4 way splitter" to me than the FourWaySplitter I was using.  I actually did finally get one somewhat like yours but yours is much more elegant.  Thanx MUCH.